# Apex CRON expression to Schedule job at the end date of the Month

Tags: cron, apex, job-scheduling

I need the CRON expression to Schedule job at the end date of the Month. I have tried this :

`"0 0 22 ? * 6L"`

But it runs on the last friday of the month. I want it to run on the last day of every month.

Comment: I tried this expression too : "0 0 12 31 1/1 ? *". But it displays only the months which has end date 31st. End dates with 30 are not displaying. Please help me in solving this.